# Security of a desktop application's source code

Tags: appsec, source-code, desktop

How easy is it to get the source code from a desktop application?

Are there any protections in place to stop someone from viewing an application's code?

Comment: Not sure if off topic, pretty broad question, changed question title because really this is about "securing" your IP.

Comment: What language is it written in? Is it open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How easy is it to get the source code from a desktop application?

If it is open source software it is easy. If not it is harder.

> Are there any protections in place to stop someone from viewing an application's code?

This depends on the software. Usually you cannot get the full source back because in the process of compiling the original source is translated to machine code or byte code. But you can often decompile the code to get at least an idea how this software works and find bugs in it (i.e. reverse engineering). Some applications have added obfuscation and other methods to make reverse engineering harder.

Comment: +1, also this depends a lot on the source language and target platform. Anything bound for a VM (.NET, Java) can be decompiled so easily and cleanly that basically any semi capable programmer can pick it apart and modify it rather easily. There are some obfuscators and such, but using these should be viewed as simply raising the bar, not barring the door shut. Even if your generated binary is target specific machine code, again this is simply raising the bar for the kind of person it would take to reverse engineer your source. TLDR: worrying about this is as fruitful as worrying about dying.